# Deploy an executable file in netbeans with SQL Lite Database

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans

I'm deploying a solution in Netbeans using java and SQLite. After deploy the executable file content contains the application file with the database empty. Tables and data are not available.

How can I create the file including my SQL Lite Database with all the data?

Comment: Then deploy the version of the DB that you want ... it's just a file. What I usually do is deploy a "factory reset" version of the DB and on first start, I import it to the local instance. Then I can always reset simply by dropping everything and importing from the template.

Comment: My problem is that it's a client application to be distributed and end user can upload the database. I need the database predefined in my application.

Comment: What is your definition of "predefined" ?